# Can't use shrinkResources: res/resources-prod-release-stripped.ap_' specified for property 'resourceFile' does not exist

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm trying to use the shrinkResources feature.

I'm using `JackCompiler` and `JAVA_1_8`, and compiling the release version of the flavor named "prod".
This flavor is only used to take advantage of the better compile time when using the "dev" flavor with `minSdk 21`.
There are no "flavor-specific" resources. They are all in the only common res folder.

When running the compilation I get the following error.

```
:app:packageProdRelease FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong: A problem was found with the configuration of task ':app:packageProdRelease'.
File '/app/build/intermediates/res/resources-prod-release-stripped.ap_' specified for property 'resourceFile' does not exist.
```

Comment: `shrinkResources` does not work with `jack` yet.

Answer (score 9):

In order for shrinkResources to work, you must also set

```
minifyEnabled true
```

Resource shrinking requires the unused code removal step, otherwise you get the error.

It's stated in the documentation here: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code.html#shrink-resources

Answer (score 0):

In your gradle file set **'shrinkResources false'**

Comment: It worked... though what to do in case we also want to set shrinkresources to true.. This issue is coming up only after upgrading Android Studio 2.2

Comment: Hello Manuel, thank you for your answer, though the point of my question is how can I make "shrinkResources true" work on my configuration.

Answer (score -1):

are u update your android studio to 2.2?if that degrade 
 classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0'
to  classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.3'
but give up instant run